# How to read an CSV file in android?

Tags: android, file, csv

I am reading a CSV file which have format: "col1"\t"col2". As my understanding there are two methods to read an CSV file and add to array.

```
1. ReadByLine.
2. ReadNext.
```

In `Readbyline` I face issue if col2 have \n in between the string, and that is added to my second index. like ("Hi how r u"   "I am \n fine")
In readNext I face issue when my column1 is empty it return col2 value lile ("" "I am fine"). `readNext` return "I am fine".

Can any one suggest any best approach to work with this format.

Answer (score 0):

Each line in a CSV file uses `,` as a delimiter. You should read the file line by line and split the line with the above delimiter:

```
try {    
    File f = new File("source.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String line = "";

    while( ( line = br.readLine() ) != null ) {
        String[] tokens = line.split(",");
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then, `tokens.length` will give you the size.
If you have spaces the use:

```
String newString = tokens[x].trim();
```

Comment: I don't have "," please check my question i had mention my format.

Comment: Then change the delimiter

Comment: Sorry I can't do that do you any other idea to suggested